# How to change the "Active geometry column" in an sf table to a different geometry column in the same table?

Tags: r, r-sf

I have an sf table with two sfc (i.e. there are two geometry columns in the sf).  When I look at the properties of the sf, one of the two geometry columns is listed as the Active Geometry column.  How do I easily make the other geometry column the active one?

I've tried the instructions here https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/st_geometry.html, but found no joy.

Here's the expression that was not working for me:

```
sf_new_data2a <- st_set_geometry(sf_new_data2a, sf_new_data2a$geometry.1)
```

Comment: "I've tried the instructions here" - what have you tried, can we see your code please? I've used `sf::st_geometry( x ) <- value` many times and it works.

Comment: Originally, I tried sf_new_data2a <- st_set_geometry(sf_new_data2a, sf_new_data2a$`geometry.1`) ...  and that expression didn't work.  I later found something that works and it's basically what you use.  Regardless, thanks for your feedback .

Comment: when using `st_set_geometry(x, )`, the `x` is expected to be a `data.frame`, not an `sf` object.

Answer (score 5):

Just found this and it worked for me:

```
st_geometry(sf_table_name) <- "name_of_another_geometry_column"
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on the existing answer from 2020, you can also use `st_set_geometry()` inside pipes `%>%` if you have multiple geometry columns in an sf collection.

First load some sample data, in this case the `nc` dataset. Then discard all the columns except `NAME` column (and `geometry` by default as it's an `sf` object), as we don't need them for the example.

```
# example data
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

nc_name <- nc %>% 
  select(NAME)

nc_name

# Simple feature collection with 100 features and 1 field
# Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -84.32385 ymin: 33.88199 xmax: -75.45698 ymax: 36.58965
# Geodetic CRS:  NAD27
# First 10 features:
#   NAME                       geometry
# 1         Ashe MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.47276 3...
# 2    Alleghany MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.23989 3...
# 3        Surry MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.45634 3...
# 4    Currituck MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.00897 3...
# 5  Northampton MULTIPOLYGON (((-77.21767 3...
# 6     Hertford MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.74506 3...
# 7       Camden MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.00897 3...
# 8        Gates MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.56251 3...
# 9       Warren MULTIPOLYGON (((-78.30876 3...
# 10      Stokes MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.02567 3...
```

We can see that the `Geometry type` is `MULTIPOLYGON` in the second row of the printout, and next to each of the coordinates in the `geometry` column.

To make an additional geometry column for the example, let's find the centroid of the `MULTIPOLYGONS` using `st_centroid()`:

```
nc_name %>% 
  mutate(
    centroid = st_centroid(geometry)
  )

# Simple feature collection with 100 features and 1 field
# Active geometry column: geometry
# Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -84.32385 ymin: 33.88199 xmax: -75.45698 ymax: 36.58965
# Geodetic CRS:  NAD27
# First 10 features:
#   NAME                       geometry                   centroid
# 1         Ashe MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.47276 3...  POINT (-81.49823 36.4314)
# 2    Alleghany MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.23989 3... POINT (-81.12513 36.49111)
# 3        Surry MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.45634 3... POINT (-80.68573 36.41252)
# 4    Currituck MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.00897 3... POINT (-76.02719 36.40714)
# 5  Northampton MULTIPOLYGON (((-77.21767 3... POINT (-77.41046 36.42236)
# 6     Hertford MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.74506 3... POINT (-76.99472 36.36142)
# 7       Camden MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.00897 3... POINT (-76.23402 36.40122)
# 8        Gates MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.56251 3... POINT (-76.70446 36.44428)
# 9       Warren MULTIPOLYGON (((-78.30876 3... POINT (-78.11042 36.39693)
# 10      Stokes MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.02567 3... POINT (-80.23429 36.40042)
```

The geometry type of this new `centroid` column is `POINT`, as it's the centroid of each `MULTIPOLYGON`. But, we can see the geometry type of the `sf` object (second row of the printout) is still `MULTIPOLYGON`.

To change the "Active" geometry column to the centroid `POINT` geometry column, we use `st_set_geometry()`, and specify the name of the column (surrounded by `' '`):

```
nc_name %>% 
  mutate(
    centroid = st_centroid(geometry)
  ) %>% 
  st_set_geometry('centroid')

# Simple feature collection with 100 features and 1 field
# Active geometry column: centroid
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -84.05986 ymin: 34.07671 xmax: -75.8095 ymax: 36.49111
# Geodetic CRS:  NAD27
# First 10 features:
#   NAME                       geometry                   centroid
# 1         Ashe MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.47276 3...  POINT (-81.49823 36.4314)
# 2    Alleghany MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.23989 3... POINT (-81.12513 36.49111)
# 3        Surry MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.45634 3... POINT (-80.68573 36.41252)
# 4    Currituck MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.00897 3... POINT (-76.02719 36.40714)
# 5  Northampton MULTIPOLYGON (((-77.21767 3... POINT (-77.41046 36.42236)
# 6     Hertford MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.74506 3... POINT (-76.99472 36.36142)
# 7       Camden MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.00897 3... POINT (-76.23402 36.40122)
# 8        Gates MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.56251 3... POINT (-76.70446 36.44428)
# 9       Warren MULTIPOLYGON (((-78.30876 3... POINT (-78.11042 36.39693)
# 10      Stokes MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.02567 3... POINT (-80.23429 36.40042)
```

And we can see the geometry type of the `sf` object in the second row of the printout has changed to `POINT` now, but we still retain the coordinates and geometry of the original `MULTIPOLYGONS`.